# How to locate flutter AppAvailability plugin's String uri when working in an iOS environment?

Tags: ios, flutter

When using flutter_appavailability in an iOS environment: Where can I find the String uri of an app (app1) that needs to be entered on the launchApp(String uri) method of a separate app (app2), so as to intend to call the first app?

I have an app I developed in Flutter to run in iOS. I’ll refer to this as app1. Then a have a second separate app also developed in Flutter to run in iOS, which I’ll refer to as app2. Under certain circumstances, app2 should allow the option to launch app1; for this I’m using the Flutter AppAvailability plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability) method launchApp(String uri). If it was Android, the String uri would be the Package name used when creating the project; but that doesn’t work for iOS.

Where can I find the app1 String uri that needs to be entered on the launchApp(String uri) method in app2?

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of tinkering, it ended up just being the name of my app with `://` tacked on the end.  So for me, the app that I am working on is called climb so I used `climb://` as the URI and it worked for me.

On a separate note I pulled from one of the forks of the flutter_appavailability package to take advantage of null safety and android updates.  This is the one that I picked: https://github.com/Insight-Timer/flutter_appavailability.git